# ipywidgets updatable text area scrollbar

Tags: text, ipywidgets, updatable-views

Using ipywidgets, I need to create an output text box which will display alert messages.
The box should include a scroll bar to be able to read previous messages.
ipywidgets comes with Layout, Textarea and Text functionalities but I could not figure out how to use them to my particular case.
Help and suggestions would be greatly appreciated here
Thak you

Comment: Use a ipywidgets.Output, but each time before you print a new message, you can collect the existing text (widg.outputs), append the new text, clear the display and then display your new text.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.